# Any other (good) long read aligners apart kma?

Tags: sequence-alignment

I wonder if there are any other more efficient long read aligners apart kma? I have heard there is some hisat2 long read application but it's not really efficient. Any suggestions?

Comment: "Apps"? You mean aligners?

Comment: Yes, aligners. I shouldn't call them apps, I just meant some module that can be attached to a script, like bwa, minimap or that kma for ex.

Comment: "module that can be attached to a script" is not a thing. Modulefiles are a way of packaging binaries and related dependencies, so you're looking for an aligner like ATPoint says, not an app or a module. If you need a binary as a module, consult your HPC sysadmin.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and clarify your needs. If you need an aligner, then please say so (apps is meanigless). If you instead mean a variant caller, say that. Then, explain what more efficient means for you (faster? better resource utilization? less RAM specifically? something else?), and whether you are tied to a specific operating system. Perhaps also tell us what kind of sequencing you will be doing (targeted? WES? WGS?).